# Get Tasks lists from Microsoft beta Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I cannot GET data about the tasks when I use a personal account to login.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks
```

When I use my company account to login the REST request works fine,
but when I use personal accounts ( ...@outlook.com, ...@hotmail.com, ...@live.com )the request return the error response:

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": "RequestBroker-ParseUri",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'Outlook'.",
     "innerError": {
       "request-id": "d7a97e67-358a-41fa-b70b-81a2096cb4cb",
        "date": "2018-01-08T13:30:39"
           }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beta release of Graph's Outlook Tasks API doesn't support Personal/Outlook.com accounts at the moment. It is planned but there isn't an ETA available just yet.

Comment: That explanes everything. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/planner/tasks`

I'm not certain, but I think that may be what you're looking for

Comment: Hi Kevin, thank you for your response. Unfortunately  GET /planner/tasks is a completely different resource ( for example you need Group.ReadWrite.All as permission on the Microsoft portal )